# mySQL query -- conditional select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some data

```
t1
------------------
id (int)
item_id (int)
item_description (text)
showHide (enum 0,1)
```

Normally I show any results that have showHide flag set to '0'. I need to modify the query to also show results with showHide flag set to '1' if user has the corresponding item_id in another table, t2.

```
t2
------------------
id (int)
item_id (int)
usr_id (int)
```

Stuck here, not sure how to do this:

```
SELECT item_description FROM t1
// get results with  showHide = 0 
// AND 
// showHide = 1 if t1.item_id found in t2 WHERE usr_id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine 2 queries with `UNION`

```
SELECT t1.item_description
  FROM t1
 WHERE showHide = 0
UNION
    SELECT t1.item_description
      FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
     WHERE showHide = 1
```

The more tricky way, thus less performant:

```
    SELECT t1.item_description
      FROM t1
 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
     WHERE showHide = 0
        OR (showHide = 1 AND t2.item_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I don't see how 'more tricky' implicates 'less performant'. I do not argue that the second solution might be actually performing worse (not until benchmarked), just don't see the conection between 'trickiness' (a subjective term to say the least) and performance.

Comment: @Mchl: it is **less** performant because: 1) `LEFT JOIN` (which is slower than `INNER JOIN` 2) `OR` with 0/1 field (since mysql **doesn't have** bitmap type indexes) will not be optimized at all (it will be fullscan in any case).

Comment: @Mchl: the connection between `trick` and `performance` in my mind is: the more simple and obvious query almost always works better. Proven for years.

Comment: That's a generalisation however, that can lead you astray. KISS is a wonderful rule, but as any rule can be abused ;) Technical reasons you provided convince me more than `argument from simplicity`.

Comment: Would it be easier if I ran two separate queries? In the first I can get all item_ids, turn then into a comma separated string to be used in the second query. The second query would get description with flag set to 0 + (1 if the ID is found IN IDs string)? I just think if both tables have thousands of line, it may take a while to process in one query.

Comment: @santa: Easier than what? My first query is trivia and will be as fast as it possible for such case. Thousands.... :-S When you'll have hundreds of millions - come back here again with new question. Until you have just thousands - my 1st query will run terrible fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  t1.item_description
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT item_id FROM t2 WHERE usr_id = 123
) AS t2
USING (item_id)
WHERE 
  t1.showHide = 0 
OR
  (t1.showHide = 1 AND t2.item_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Nested select instead of regular `join` with `ON` can decrease performance dramatically.

Comment: It's uncorrelated subquery. Unless you're working on MySQL 4.x it works fine.

Comment: @Mchl: the fact that it is not correlated one doesn't mean that mysql will perform it just once. For mysql it is true, that something written in documentation is not absolutely true irl. Also - you lose the ability of using composite index (`user_id + item_id`) to make your query faster, and for looking for `USING(item_id)` you'll **always** get a scan over result set from nested query.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into it, cause I use such queries quite often. Thanks.

Comment: @Mchl: for first - compare `EXPLAIN` for them, but I bet you know it yourself ;-)